# DD-WRT Firmware Upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I use DD-WRT for my routers WRT400N

Followed these instructions
https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT400N

and then also i see in the router database
https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database
and these firmware are from 2013-04-22

Questions
1. Are these any newer firmware than this, where can i get the latest firmware for DD-WRT?
2. Are the Beta stable enough for home use?

Issues
I am having some intermittent connectivity issues and router reboot schedule not working as expected

Comment: Are you currently having any issues with the routers?

Comment: I am having some intermittent connectivity issues and router reboot schedule not working as expected

Comment: This seems like it would be helpful to you.  http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=1000317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few places to check for newer firmware's

1. http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads

   ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/

   for your WRT400N i even see a beta from yesterday 2/17/2016
2. Regarding betas, it's always a risk so use at your own discretion

Based on the date you mentioned it seems you are already running a beta 21061

I am currently using DD-WRT v3.0-r27506 (07/09/15) since 7/9/15 itself i think and it's been running very stable

I also had issues with routers slowing down, heating and require daily reboot. and then i found out my root cause was they were in a closet with no air ventilation so since then i moved them out in the open and following is my uptime

Time: 10:11:59 up 106 days, 15:19, load average: 0.07, 0.03, 0.04

Comment: I am tempted to just try the 2/17/2016 build :)

Comment: hacking the routers in itself is risky because you run the risk of bricking them. If a particular firmware breaks something wait for the next one and hope it will fix it. These WRT400N are very cheap. you can always get a new one ebay for like $15 :)

Comment: An issue that i ran into was the main Ethernet cable (that connects your router to ISP's one) was too close to some power cables. The electric field generated by the power cables was too strong, therefore messed up with the field generated by the Ethernet cable. My routers and switches froze up and I had to reboot them on a daily base until I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

The latest (beta) versions of DD-WRT can be found [here](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2016).

DD-WRT hasn't had a non-beta release in a long time, and this is the only place with recent developments. As for whether they're stable to use, it's very hard to say, you will need to try it and judge for yourself. In my case, the official release breaks if I use WPA2 (Nobody can then log into the router) and I have to use the latest betas.